# Power bi calculation containsrow dont work

Tags: powerbi, dax, contains, calculation

I have 3 columns TPLNR, TXT04 and INACT. If value isTPLNR has the DLFL value in field TXT04 and it has a "X" in field INACT the data most not be displayed in my visual or i need to get true of false in the column so that i can select the my visual.

The error what iam getting is

The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

```
CALCULATE (
    IF (
        CONTAINSROW ( VALUES ( FunctionalLocation[TXT04] ), "DLFL" ),
        VALUES ( FunctionalLocation[INACT] ),
        "X"
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( FunctionalLocation, FunctionalLocation[TPLNR] )
)
```

But it's not working. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's "not working" isn't enough information to go on. Are you getting an error? If not, in what way is it not working?

Comment: i have 3 columns TPLNR, TXT04 and INACT. If value isTPLNR has the DLFL value in field TXT04 and it has a "X" in field INACT the data most not be displayed in my visual or i need to get true of false in the column so that i can select the my visual.

 the error what iam getting is 

The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely due to `VALUES ( FunctionalLocation[INACT] )`:

> The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

A measure must return a single value but VALUES can return multiple values so you need to handle that possibility somehow. For example, you could use SELECTEDVALUE instead of VALUES, which returns a blank when there are multiple values.

Comment: Hi Alexis, i have adapted the measure:

CALCULATE (
IF(
        CONTAINSROW ( SELECTEDVALUE(  FunctionalLocation[TXT04] ), "DLFL" ), SELECTEDVALUE(  FunctionalLocation[INACT] ), "X"    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( FunctionalLocation, FunctionalLocation[TPLNR] )
)

but iam getting the error The CONTAINSROW function expects a table expression for argument '1', but a string or numeric expression was used.

Comment: You still want the first VALUES within CONTAINSROW. Sorry that wasn't clear.